# C# invoke chained delegate methods asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates

Suppose I have a `delegate` which refers to `bar` number of methods. When I invoke the delegate either like this `someDelegate(someParameter);` or like this `someDelegate.Invoke(someParameter);`, methods that this delegate refers to are actually invoked synchronously, one after another, right? Is there a way to make this calls Asynchronous ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`. That will call all the individual delegates asynchronously - but still serially. (You should then call `EndInvoke` in the callback you pass into `BeginInvoke`. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/2e08f6yc.aspx) for more details.)

If you want to call the delegates in *parallel*, you could use [`MulticastDelegate.GetInvocationList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.getinvocationlist.aspx) to get them individually, then something like [`Parallel.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke.aspx) to invoke them.

Comment: Jon, `Parallel.Invoke` cannot be used with ` MulticastDelegate.GetInvocationList` directly. OP needs `Action` to use `Parallel.Invoke`. Correct me if am wrong

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: The exact operation would depend on the original delegate type, which we don't know about. (We don't know if the OP even wants to invoke them in parallel.) That's why I put "something like" - if the OP wants more concrete details, they'll need to provide more concrete requirements.

Comment: +1 for hinting at the difference between "asynchronous" and "parallel" and pointing at a solution for both. A concrete code example for the latter (`GetInvocationList`) might have been helpful, though.

Comment: @stakx: I'm happy to provide a concrete code example if the OP can give more details of what they're actually trying to do. I don't want to provide a concrete code example which addresses a different requirement :(